# BlackBerry - How can i show a Label with emoticons?

Tags: user-interface, blackberry, graphics, drawing, emoticons

I need to show a Label with emoticons included already in the blackbery interface, with flags, etc.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such built-in functionality.

With net available you can use [BrowserField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/418105/embedded-html-control-for-blackberry) or [WebBitmapField](http://www.coderholic.com/blackberry-webbitmapfield/).

Otherwise you can use local resources + [BitmapField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1426299/blackberry-draw-image-on-the-screen). I wouldn't advice to use LabelField with custom drawing, just add simple LabelField before or after BitmapField with emoicon.

**UPDATE:**
See alternative answer at [Blackberry: Emoticons in Chat Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7268276/blackberry-emoticons-in-chat-application/7861476#7861476)

Comment: sorry i can not give you karma.... i only have 11 on my reputation and i need 15 :)

Comment: thats OK, you can always came again ;) !

Comment: The solution won't work if the emoticon is in the middle of the text... in which case Timoto will need to derive a custom LabelField

Comment: it's obvious you'll have to split text into 2 LabelFields, which will be better for layout, more simple and bugfree

Comment: I have the same requirement as timoto.  The LabelField/BitmapField/LabelField mechanism also has shortcomings when it comes to word wrap.  I solved this by tokenizing the text into words, and then using a FlowFieldManager to put words and images together in a paragraph-like view.  However, this is slow, doesn't work for right-to-left languages, and also doesn't work for text input.  It's pretty much a hack, whereas overriding the paint and layout methods of TextField would do everything nicely and efficiently - unfortunately it is not possible to do that.

Comment: @Michael it shouldn't be so slow if you split text only in two cases: when image should be placed and on newline. using TextEditField gives you text input. Sure there will be other issues, but they can be solved too. I am agree that overriding paint and layout would be a best solution, but it's so buggy!