# how to display html content in blackberry 4.6.1

Tags: blackberry-storm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Embedded HTML control for Blackberry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/418105/embedded-html-control-for-blackberry)

how to display html content in blackberry 4.6.1
any body help me
thanks for any help

Answer (score -1):

You can use BrowserField to display HTML content in BlackBerry like so:

```
BrowserField myBrowserField = new BrowserField();

myBrowserField.displayContent("<html><body><h1>Hello World!</h1></body></html>",
    "http://localhost");
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: BrowserField not available in blackberry 4.6.1